# SQL query, comparing two arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an application with images stored in multiple categories, currently being stored by category ID in a column as a space separated list (eg. 1 5 23 2).

I have a query from a search filter, which is currently an array of IDs, (eg. 1 5).

Ideally, I'd find a solution using something like WHERE IN that would see if any of my array values exist in the stored column, although I don't see an easy solution.

At the moment I have to query all the images, bring them into PHP and check there, using "array_intersect". I see this as being a problem if I have 100,000s of images in the future to pull and then check.

Can anyone think of an elegant solution? The application is still in development, so I could arguably change the structure of my tables.

Comment: The elegant solution would be to NOT store the IDs in the database the way you do it.  You should store one image ID per row, then your query would be much-much simpler.   I strongly suggest that you modify your schema before it's too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding a map table would probably be best here which maps the image_id with the category_id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now that you've said it, it's gleamingly obvious! So, a third table with the corresponding IDs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

refactor your database tables!!!

use sth like this:

table_image
id int
name text,
content text,
...

and a second table for the categories:

table_category
id int,
image_id int,
category int

this way, you can store categories in a separate table using foreign keys. now, you can do simple sql queries like

SELECT table_image.id FROM table_image, table_category WHERE table_image.id = table_category.image_id and table_category.category = $cat_arr[0] OR  table_category.category = $cat_arr[1] ...

Comment: Thanks! Already done it, I think I was just having a brain burp.

Answer (score 1):

H Hatfield has the best answer. If you really must use a single column (which I do not recommend) you could store the categories as a comma separated list instead of spaces. You can then use the MySql function [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), as such:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', categoryListColumnName) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET('15', categoryListColumnName) > 0
```

Using your current database design you could use an IN query:

```
WHERE categoryListColumnName LIKE '% 3 %' OR categoryListColumnName LIKE '% 15 %'
```

and add more OR's for every category you want to find. When using this query you have to make sure your list separated by spaces ends and starts with a space, otherwise it won't work.

Let me just reiterate, that these methods will work, but they are not recommended.